# Firestore query where field is not equal to value using indexes with onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all unseen messages that the current user has in conversation. The problem is that I do not know how to exclude other user seen messages and get only current user seen messages so I can do `allMessages - allReadMessages = unread messages count`

**This is my function that tries to achieve what I explained:**

```
//helper to get unread messages count
  async getUnseenMessagesCount(chatAuthor) {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath)
    try {
      collectionRef
    .get()
    .then(() => {
      collectionRef
        .where('seenBy', '==', '')
        .orderBy('author')
        .where('author', '>', store.getters['authentication/user'].id)
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snapshot.docs.length)
            if (snap.type === 'added') {
              store.commit(
                'chats/setUnreadMessagesCount',
                snapshot.docs.length
              )
              f.push(snapshot.docs.length)
            }
          })
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })       } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

**These are the indexes inside firebase(are they even needed in my case?):**

[image]

How can I achieve what I explained? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't use `await` with onSnapshot becuase it doesn't return a promise.  onSnapshot returns a registration object that you can use to unsubscribe the listener you passed.  If you want to query a single time with no listener, use `get()` instead on `onSnapshot()`, which does return a promise that can be awaited.

Comment: @DougStevenson But I do have to listen the chane on realtime. Without onSnapshot i can not do that, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you need listeners, then use them.  `await` is just not going to do what you expect, since the onSnapshot doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did remove all awaits and kept onSnapshot function but it doesn't make much difference. Result is same.

Comment: @DougStevenson To be honest I actually knew that, those awaits were there and I forgot them there if I tried possible solutions

Comment: The reason why I bring it up is because seeing those awaits there is making it hard for me, as the reader of this code, to figure out what the author intends for it to do. It looks like you added a try/catch in there now. That also might not work the way you expect, since it won't catch any errors from the listener functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson I did update question code.

Answer (score 0):

When I user firestore for the first time, these things was also a problem for me. Being very hard to do a simple count query.

So for your question, the simple answer is you can get the authenticated user id and add another where query something like

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User logged in already or has just logged in.
    console.log(user.uid);
  } else {
    // User not logged in or has just logged out.
  }
});
```

```
.where('userId', '==', userId)
```

But my suggestion is to use a firebase function to count the number of unseen messages using firestore triggers. So in your function you would do something like

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.countUnseenMessages = functions.firestore
  .document('...')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    // increase number of unseen messages to the relevant user
  });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this does not help me much since I know that all already.

Comment: Or maybe I misunrerstood you :)