# Getting documents with specific value in angular using firebase realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have database which look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXRf3.png)

And angular app in which i want to get messages from document where members are equal to friendUid and userUid which i pass to the function. I have function in service which look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { AngularFireDatabase } from "@angular/fire/compat/database";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class ChatService{

    chat: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){}

    changeDisplayedMessage(friendUid: string, userUid: string){
        this.chat = this.db.list('/chats/', ref => {
            console.log(ref);
            return ref;
        }).valueChanges();
        
        this.chat.subscribe({
            next: (result) => {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }

}
```

It enables me to get all chats and log output (result) like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSNAI.png)

Also i am importing firebase in app.module.ts in this way (I remove unnecessary details like added components):

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database'
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage'
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am not really sure if what i am doing is right approach it seems like there is another method of importing database in which methods are used in slighty different way, but at the beginning i have found a lot of tutorials which were showing this approach. In

```
this.chat = this.db.list('/chats/', ref => {
            console.log(ref);
            return ref;
        }).valueChanges();
```

I am getting reference to my collections so it works fine, and i know i can use methods on ref to filter data in some way, but still i don't know how to access members, beacuse i would have to go to '/chats/userUid/' to get them, but i don't want to go to specific user, instead i want to search through all chats and find one which have members with same uids as friendUid and UserUid. This is my first time using nosql database and i find myself trying to recreated select query in some way but i don't know if it's good approach. If you have a idea how to get this data using fireabase and angular fire this is what i am looking for, but thoughs about structuring my database would be also helpful.

Before implementing my database this way i was trying to recreate one from this question: [Firebase realtime database structure in chat app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535831/firebase-realtime-database-structure-in-chat-app) but i find it hard to get to chatUid and have basiclly same problem beacuse i don't how to get to lower fields of document. Also documentation which i found on github doesn't seem to give clear examples of how to use angularfire.